# How to capture iOS camera and publish RTMP live stream?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, h.264, rtmp, aac

I have completed an RTMP player on iOS, using FFmpeg to decode `flv1` video and `speex` audio. Now I want to capture iOS camera and decode H.264 video and AAC audio, then publish video and audio stream to RTMP server, Red5 server as the player programe used before. I know that I should recompile FFmpeg, adding `libx264` and `libaacplus` to support iOS video and audio decoding. But then how to publish RTMP live stream? Using `RTMP_Write()`? `RTMP_SendPacket()`? Please just tell me some thoughts or solutions, or it's very generous of you to show me some code. Thanks!

Reference: [capture camera and publish video with librtmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629913/capture-camera-and-publish-video-with-librtmp)

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg supports rtmp input and output both with an internal protocol ("rtmp") and from an external library ("librtmp"). The only reason I know of to choose the internal or librtmp version over the other is for specific server support -- i.e. one may work better for you than another for a given server.

In FFmpeg, RTMP video is muxed to flv and so long as your output path/uri begins with "rtmp://..." it should just work for you. Nothing is *stopping you* from using librtmp directly, of course -- but why bother?

Configuring your server to accept streams, and to know what endpoint to view the stream on, can be it's own little adventure.

(Disclaimer: I'm pretty much doing this right now, so I know it's possible and straightforward.)

Comment: Now I have complete publish rtmp audio data. It means rtmp server is ok. then i try to capture camera to get raw yuv420p data then send to rtmp publisher. i googled and see most of articles about transforming to rgb image. do you know this? can we chat using im?

Comment: @SmeegolXie Are you trying to send raw video to your RTMP server? What is doing the video and audio encoding? What is doing the muxing before streaming out to RTMP?